# AttributeError: module 'metpy.units' has no attribute 'knots'

Tags: units-of-measurement, metpy

I am trying to add basic units to my array to do calculations with Metpy. Using the function call metpy.units.meters (or .knots or .degrees) is not working.

Here is my code snippet:

```
import metpy.units as mpunits

...

wind_speed = webSKNT.values * mpunits.knots
wind_dir = webDRCT .values * mpunits.degrees
webu, webv = mpcalc.wind_components(wind_speed, wind_dir)
```

where webSKNT and webDRCT are pandas dataframes.

Here's the error I keep getting:
AttributeError: module 'metpy.units' has no attribute 'knots'

and I get a similar error if I try: mpunits.meters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the import like that, you need to do:

```
mpunits.units.knots
```

The canonical way we usually suggest to get the unit registry is:

```
from metpy.units import units
```

which then allows you to write:

```
units.knots
```